# row_number in data sets. Row_number apis is resulting in a data frame.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

Can anyone let me know how to get row_number in data sets. Row_number apis is resulting in a data frame. I dont want to convert a dataset to a data frame and then back to data set just for row_number calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `Datasets` works in Spark is that if you apply any transformation to them they get converted into `Dataframe` which internally is `Dataset[Row]` and this behavior is only logical. Let me explain it to you using an example.

Suppose you have following case class.

```
case class Person(SSN: Int, Name: String)
```

and you have a `Dataset[Person]` with reference `people`

Now if you do `people.withColumn("row_number", row_number())` the schema of this no longer fits the `Person` class and has to be converted to generic `Row` type hence `Dataset[Person]` becomes `Dataset[Row] / Dataframe`.

So if you want to add row_number and still want it to be a `Dataset[Person]` I would suggest you add an extra field to your case class.

```
case class Person(SSN: Int, Name: String, row_number: Long)
```

That way when you add a new column `row_number` each row will still conform to the case class `Person` and won't get converted to generic `Row` type.